# Admob data not showing up in Firebase

Tags: firebase, admob

My app is live in the App Store. Admob ads are working fine, Firebase is logging events correctly, and my Admob and Firebase accounts are linked. However, Firebase is showing zero ad activity even though Admob is showing some meager earnings. How do I get my Admob data to migrate over to Firebase?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because query not relating to programming.

Comment: Perhaps a silly question, but have you linked your AdMob app registration to your Firebase project? https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6383165